# Send unsigned char string from native client module to browser

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

In a chrome NaCl extension that encrypts the data received from the browser and supposed to return the encrypted text via `PostMessage()` I am having trouble in sending the data type of `unsigned char*` for `ciphertext`. The [pp::Var](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_var) specification doesn't mentions anything about such form of data. I tried converting `unsigned char` to `std::string` but did not find a suitable way to do so. My code snippet is as follows:

```
if(action == "encryption")
    {
      pp::Var var_content = dict_message.Get("content");
      if (!var_action.is_string())
        return;
      std::string content = var_content.AsString();

      //encryption code starts here
      const char *password = "password";
      unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH], iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
      int len = content.length()+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH;
      unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char*)malloc(len*sizeof(unsigned char));

      aes_init(password, (int)strlen(password), key, iv);
      len = encrypt((unsigned char*)(content.c_str()), (int)strlen(content.c_str()), key, iv, ciphertext);

      pp::Var var_reply(ciphertext);
      PostMessage(var_reply);
      free(ciphertext);
    }
```

This returns a compile time error:

```
crest.cc:55:15: error: calling a private constructor of class 'pp::Var'
      pp::Var var_reply(ciphertext);
              ^
/home/kunal/Downloads/nacl_sdk/pepper_41/include/ppapi/cpp/var.h:318:3: note: declared private here
  Var(void* non_scriptable_object_pointer);
  ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [pnacl/Release/crest.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor that is private is not the one you want. Try casting the ciphertext to a (const char*):

```
pp::Var var_reply(static_cast<const char*>(ciphertext));
```

Note that this expects a UTF8 string. If your encrypted data is not in this format (it likely isn't) this will not work properly. You probably want to send this as an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_stable/cpp/classpp_1_1_var_array_buffer) instead, which allows an arbitrary byte sequence (untested, assuming len is the length of the encrypted ciphertext):

```
pp::VarArrayBuffer buffer(len);
void* buffer_ptr = buffer.Map();
memcpy(buffer_ptr, ciphertext, len);
buffer.Unmap();
PostMessage(buffer);
```

Then in JavaScript, the object you'll receive is an [JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).

You can read the data from this by using a [typed array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray):

```
function handleMessage(e) {
  var buffer = e.data;
  var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  ...
}
```